# Unsupported Media Type in postman

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing spring security with oauth2 and jwt.
the below is my login function

```
function doLogin(loginData) {

    $.ajax({
        url :  back+"/auth/secret",
        type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(loginData),
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        async : false,
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            setJwtToken(data.token);


        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("an unexpected error occured: " + errorThrown);
            window.location.href= back+'/login_page.html';
        }
    });
}
```

And down I have the Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "auth/secret", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, Device device) throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println();
        logger.info("authentication request : " + authenticationRequest.getUsername() + " " + authenticationRequest.getPassword());
        // Perform the security
         System.out.println( authenticationRequest.getUsername()+"is the username and "+authenticationRequest.getPassword());
        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                        authenticationRequest.getPassword()


                        )


        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        logger.info("authentication passed");

        // Reload password post-security so we can generate token
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails, device);
        logger.info("token " + token);

        // Return the token
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(token));
    }
```

But when I try the post request with the postman it shows me

```
{
  "timestamp": 1488973010828,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryY4KgeeQ9ONtKpvkQ;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path": "/TaxiVis/auth/secret"
}
```

But when I do  `cosole.log(data)` in the ajax call it prints the token?I could not figure out what is wrong.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data; You are not sending a json payload

Comment: What does that mean? Could you please explain?

Comment: That means your request is wrong because the mapping method at your controller, using @RequestBody, is waiting for a json object. You need to set the header Content-Type as application-json in postman and put the json object you want to send at the body section as raw. https://www.google.com/search?q=postman%20json%20post&&rct=j

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You need to set the `content-type` in postman as JSON (application/json).

Go to the body inside your POST request, there you will find the raw option.

Right next to it, there will be a drop down, select JSON (application.json).

Comment: It is in JSON only

Comment: in ur request mapping u can specifically add @consumes with values as application/json to work with JSON object

Comment: Just to be clear, the dropdown only appears to the right once you've selected the "raw" option.

Comment: Sometimes in the request-BODY, you have to put (at the least) some empty brackets.  Aka       {}

Answer (score 14):

i was also having a similar issue. in my case i made two changes

Click on headers tag and add a key 'Content-Type' with Value 'application/json'

[image]

Second step is to click on Body tab and select 'raw' radio button and select type as 'JSON' from dropdown as shown below

[image]

Comment: This was the right answer for me - seems like a bug in Postman that this is necessary.

Answer (score 13):

`Http 415 Media Unsupported` is responded back only when the content type header you are providing is not supported by the application.

With POSTMAN, the `Content-type` header you are sending is `Content type 'multipart/form-data` not `application/json`. While in the ajax code you are setting it correctly to `application/json`. Pass the correct Content-type header in POSTMAN and it will work.

Answer (score 6):

I also got this error .I was using Text inside body after changing to XML(text/xml) , got result as expected.

- If your request is XML Request  use XML(text/xml).
- If your request is JSON Request use JSON(application/json)

Answer (score 5):

If you are still failing with Unsupported Media Type in postman
when calling a SOAP endpoint you could try:

**Content-Type: application/soap+xml**

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I had authentication on the authentication tab set up to pass credentials in body.

This error occurred for me when I had the Body set to None.

So I needed an empty body in postman, set to raw JSON to allow this to work even though my main request was parameters in the querystring.

```
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When this was happening with me in XML;
I just changed "application/XML" to be "text/XML",
which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In PostMan is was facing issue so i solved it by selecting the format for raw data from text to JSON then after it started working!
[image]