# JAVA REST jersy + Eclipse + MYSQL insert data into db

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, eclipse, web-services

I am new to webservices, 
inside chrome debugger getting error:
http://localhost:8080/CRUDrestApp/REST/WebService/addUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

And in postman app getting error:
http://localhost:8080/CRUDrestApp/REST/WebService/addUser?regUserName=a
status: 415 Unsupported Media Type

To fix this errors what necessary changes I have to do?

FeedService.java>>

```
package webService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import model.ProjectManager;
import model.AddUserManager;
import model.GetUserManager;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import dto.FeedObjects;
import dto.AddUserObject;

@Path("/WebService")
public class FeedService {
    //for insert query
    @POST
    @Path("/addUser")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public void reguserdata(AddUserObject reguserData)
    {
        String feeds  = null;
        try 
        {       
            //StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            System.out.println("Inside reguserdata");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            System.out.println("Inside add User web service::"+gson.toJson(reguserData));
            feeds = gson.toJson(reguserData);
            AddUserManager projectManager= new AddUserManager();
            projectManager.SetFeeds(feeds);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

AddUser.Java>>>

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dto.AddUserObject;


public class AddUser {



    public  ArrayList<AddUserObject> GetFeeds(Connection connection, String receivedData) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<AddUserObject> regData = new ArrayList<AddUserObject>();
        String receivedData1 = receivedData;
        try
        {
            //String uname = request.getParameter("uname");

            //PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from users");
            //ps.setString(1,uname);
                //PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into users(username,password,hint1,hint2,emailid,uid) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into users (username) values (?)");

                AddUserObject feedObject = new AddUserObject();

                 System.out.println("Add>>receivedData1.valueOf(0):"+receivedData1.valueOf(0)); 
                 feedObject.setRegUserName(receivedData1.valueOf(0));



                 System.out.println("Add>>getRegUserName:"+feedObject.getRegUserName());                
                 ps.setString(1, feedObject.getRegUserName());              
//               ps.setString(2, feedObject.getRegPassword());
//               ps.setString(3, feedObject.getRegHint1());
//               ps.setString(4, feedObject.getRegHint2());
//               ps.setString(5, feedObject.getRegEmail());
//               ps.setString(6, feedObject.getRegUid());

                 regData.add(feedObject);


             ps.executeUpdate();
             ps.close();
            return regData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

AddUserObject.java>>>

```
package dto;

public class AddUserObject {

    private String regId;
    private String regusername;
    private String regpassword;
    private String reghint1;
    private String reghint2;
    private String regemail;
    private String reguid;


    /**
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getRegId() {
        return regId;
    }
    /**
     * @param reguid  to set
     */
    public void setRegId(String regId) {
        this.regId = regId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the title
     */
    public String getRegUserName() {
        return regusername;
    }
    /**
     * @param title the title to set
     */
    public void setRegUserName(String regusername) {
        this.regusername = regusername;
    }
    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getRegPassword() {
        return regpassword;
    }
    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setRegPassword(String regpassword) {
        this.regpassword = regpassword;
    }
    /**
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getRegHint1() {
        return reghint1;
    }
    /**
     * @param url the url to set
     */
    public void setRegHint1(String reghint1) {
        this.reghint1 = reghint1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getRegHint2() {
        return reghint2;
    }
    /**
     * @param url the url to set
     */
    public void setRegHint2(String reghint2) {
        this.reghint2 = reghint2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getRegEmail() {
        return regemail;
    }
    /**
     * @param reguid  to set
     */
    public void setRegEmail(String regemail) {
        this.regemail = regemail;
    }

    /**
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getRegUid() {
        return reguid;
    }
    /**
     * @param reguid  to set
     */
    public void setRegUid(String reguid) {
        this.reguid = reguid;
    }
}
```

AddUserManeger.java>>>

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dao.Database;
import dao.AddUser;
import dto.AddUserObject;

public class AddUserManager {


    public static ArrayList<AddUserObject> SetFeeds(String feeds2)throws Exception {
        ArrayList<AddUserObject> feeds = null;
        String receivedData = feeds2;
        try {
                Database database= new Database();
                Connection connection = database.Get_Connection();
                AddUser project= new AddUser();
                feeds=project.GetFeeds(connection , receivedData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return feeds;
    }

}
```

app.js>>

```
 var app = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
var baseUrl ="http://localhost:8080/CRUDrestApp/REST/WebService";  
console.log("Inside App js");
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
             }). 
            when('/register', {
               templateUrl: 'register.html',
               controller: 'registerCtrl'
            }).  
            when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            });
         }]);


app.controller('NavController', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    }); 

    $scope.getClass = function (path) {
    if(path === '/') {
        if($location.path() === '/') {
            return "active";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) {
        return "active";
    } else {
        return "";
    }

}
});

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($http, $scope, $timeout) {

});

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($http, $scope, $timeout) {

});

console.log("after route provider");
app.controller('registerCtrl', function($http, $scope, $timeout) {
  console.log('inside registerAppCtrl controller');

    $scope.addUser = function() {
        var userdetails = JSON.stringify($scope.userAdd);
        console.log("$scope.userAdd::"+userdetails);
        if($scope.userAdd.regUserName == "" || $scope.userAdd.regUserPass == "" || $scope.userAdd.regUserCPass == "" || $scope.userAdd.regHint1 == "" || $scope.userAdd.regHint2 == ""){
            console.log('Insert mandatory field values');
        }
        else{   
                    $.ajax({
                        url: baseUrl + '/addUser',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'post',
                        contentType: 'application/json ',
                        data: userdetails,
                        success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                        //$('#response pre').html( data );
                        console.log("successfully retrived response from server:::"+data);
                        /* console.log(data); */
                        $scope.userAdd = '';
                    },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                            console.log( errorThrown );
                        }
                    });     
        }
     };
});
```

Register.html

```
<section id="" ng-controller="registerCtrl">    
<form>
<div>
    User Name
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userAdd.regUserName" required>
</div>
<div>
    Password
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" ng-model="userAdd.regUserPass" >
</div>
<div>
    Confirm Password
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" ng-model="userAdd.regUserCPass" >
</div>
<div>
    Enter Hint1
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userAdd.regHint1" >
</div>
<div>
    Enter Hint2
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userAdd.regHint2" >
</div>
<div>
    Enter UID
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userAdd.regUid" >
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register" ng-click="addUser()">
</div>
<div>
    <a href="login.html" target="_self">Login</a>
</div>
</form>

</section>
```

Comment: Try to debug your program. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670413/unsupported-media-type-in-postman) SO Postman question.

Answer (score 0):

make an empty constructor in your AddUserObject.java

```
public AddUserObject(){}
```

Comment: System.out.println("Inside add User web service::"+gson.toJson(reguserData)); does this line print something ? if no may be you didn't certain content-type in your postman client.

Comment: No it doesn't print anything. Some one help me to fix it plz

Comment: Issue resolved by using data type as a string inside web service parameter instead of addUserObject