# Laravel PHP compact function in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, php, laravel, .net-core

Me and my clients want to move to .NET so I still didn't get it to return more than 1 vars/strings in .NET. How to return something like this in .NET?

```
    //Verdienst für Heute ausrechnen
    $clicksToCoinsToday = Click::whereIn('short_link_id', $short_link_id)->whereDate('created_at', $today)->sum('click_amount');

    //Verdienst für letzte 7 Tage ausrechnen
    $clicksToCoinsLast7Days = Click::whereIn('short_link_id', $short_link_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $lastweek)->sum('click_amount');

    return view('dashboard.admin.nutzerProfil', compact('nutzerDaten', 'clicksToCoinsYesterday', 'clicksToCoinsToday', 'clicksToCoinsLast7Days', 'allCoins'));
```

In C#

```
    public ActionResult GetClicks(List<Click> clicks, string clicksCount)
    {
        clicks =  _context.Clicks.ToList();

        clicksCount = _context.Clicks.Count().ToString();

        return (clicks, clicksCount);
    }
```

I wanted to get Clicks to List and also count how many of them are in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, I would recommend you should create a custom model representing the data needed for your view.

for example

```cs
public class ClicksViewModel
{
    public int ClicksCount{get;set;}
    public List<Clicks> Clicks{get;set;}
}
```

And then

```cs
return View(new ClicksViewModel(){ ClicksCount = clicksCount, Clicks = clicks });
```

In the view:

```html
Model.ClicksCount;
Model.Clicks;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also working with Web API? Because you wrote "return View".

Comment: @YanMalinovskiy ,for api just do `return OK(new ClicksViewModel(){ ClicksCount = clicksCount, Clicks = clicks })`

Comment: Visual Studio shows no problems, but Postman returns me 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Comment: @YanMalinovskiy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670413/unsupported-media-type-in-postman